# Blackberry OS 4.5 and higher with jQuery

Tags: blackberry, mobile, jquery-mobile, blackberry-jde

I know this question has been asked several times but I didn't find the answer I was looking for. I am creating one Blackberry App (using Browserfield API) to invoke mobile web pages that would be supported on all devices from OS versions 4.5 and higher.

1. Can I display plain jQuery web pages using BrowserField in Blackberry OS version 4.5 and higher?
2. If so, what version of jQuery library works on Blackberry OS Versions 4.5 & higher?
3. If it is not possible, am I left with plain java script?

Comment: I would't use javascript with BlackBerry OS before version 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this document-

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_forms_513051_11.jsp

Looks like OS 4.6 or higher, you could get away with plain Jquery.